# Mocking an attribute of a class regardless of constructor signature

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, constructor-injection

**Class**

```
public class Foo {
  private MyClass obj;

  public Foo(String s, int i, boolean b) {
    MyOtherClass otherObj = OtherClassFactory.getInstance();
    this.obj = new MyClass(s, i, b, otherObj);
  }

  //More Code
}
```

Constructor takes some arguments, retrieves an instance from a factory, and uses all these local variables to instantiate the one attribute it has (`obj`).

However, all I care about is mocking `obj` itself. I don't care about any of the arguments to the constructor, nor `otherObj`.

I've tried injecting just the attribute:

```
public class FooTest {
  @Mock
  private MyClass fakeObj;
  @InjectMocks
  private Foo foo;

  //More Code
}
```

But this doesn't work, complaining:

> Cannot instantiate `@InjectMocks` field named '`foo`' of type '`class Foo`'.
>   You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to
>   construct the instance. However the constructor or the initialization
>   block threw an exception : `OtherClassFactory` has not been initialized.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so how?  If not, and I need to mock `OtherClassFactory`, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would provide a second constructor, package-private, like this.

```
public Foo(String s, int i, boolean b) {
    this(new MyClass(s, i, b, OtherClassFactory.getInstance());
}

Foo(MyClass obj) {
   this.obj = obj;
}
```

Then in your test, you can just write

```
Foo toTest = new Foo(mockMyClass);
```

where `mockMyClass` is your Mockito mock.

Comment: Exactly what I would do as well.